# Where can I find BCEL 6.0 and how can I modify it adding a patch?

Tags: java, bytecode, bcel

I used for my project BCEL-5.2 and after few months I realized that it doesn't contain the class for the local variable type table. I saw that is present in BCEL-6.0 and I found also a patch to apply at it.

Where can I find the source code of this library?

Anybody know how to get the library after adding the patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 6.0 was not released yet, but you can get its source from the [BCEL code repository](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/source-repository.html).

Answer (score 1):

Version 6.0 is now out for Java 7.

[download](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/download_bcel.cgi)